# Transferring entire drive image over to ssd

Tags: hard-disk, ssd

So, I'm replacing my laptop's 1TB hard drive with a 1TB sata ssd, and I'm wondering how to transfer the files from one to another. I'm dual booting kubuntu 17.10 and windows 10, and I'd like to keep it that way. I'm ok with a reinstall on windows, as I don't use it that much anyways, and I'd be ok with a kubuntu reinstall as well, as I've been having some problems I can't fix, no matter however long I spend researching them or asking questions.

Other than just backing my stuff on an external hard drive, is there anything else I should know about?
Thanks.

Comment: The problem with naive cloning is that not all "1TB" drives are the same size. This could result in a damaged filesystem if the new drive is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You intend to copy over your valuable files, right. But what if you forget on one or two.

This answer addresses the issue of cloning the whole partition in case you forget on something.

---

Suppose your laptop's hard drive is named:

```
/dev/sda
```

Further suppose your Linux partition is for instance:

```
/dev/sda2
```

And finally suppose that your external HDD is mounted as:

```
/mnt/externalhdd
```

---

Then you might want to do a *perfect copy* of it, for example this way:

1. Boot from a live Linux USB.
2. Become root:

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```
3. Install `pv`, or if you don't need to see progress, you might use `cat`:

   ```
   pv < /dev/sda2 > /mnt/externalhdd/sda2.pv
   ```
4. It came to be very handy to me to have a copy of the drive's partition in case I forgot something to copy over.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

## Use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) to clone your current disk in the new one, and Bob's your uncle!

---

but, if you want to have fun, you can do `fdisk -l /dev/sda | head -1 && fdisk -l /dev/sdb | head -1` ( or, more concisely `fdisk -l | awk '/Disk.*sd(a|b)/'` ) where `/dev/sda` is your current disk and `/dev/sdb` is your new disk, to print something like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
```

take note of the number of bytes of each disk: it's important for what follows.

## If your disks have exactly the same number of bytes

(and, maybe, but not ideally, if your current disk is smaller than the new one)

---

> If in your `dd` command (*read bellow*) you put a wrong device file in **if** *[inputfile]*, it's not a big
>   deal: you can do it that again, but, ***beware***: `dd` **can be
>   dangerous**... if you put a wrong device file in **of** *[outputfile]*,
>   say, for example, */dev/sdc*, another disk of yours in your system,
>   you instantly destroy the data in your */dev/sdc*, overwriting them
>   with the data in your **if** *[inputfile]* ; so, check your **of** *[outpufile]* several times.

---

You can use `dd` command from your *kubuntu* system to make and **EXACT** copy [*clone*] (*byte by byte*) {`dd` does't understand about *filesystems*... it's a *dummy* copy, *byte by byte* and, ideally, both disks need to have the exact same number of bytes} ;
this can be slow, specially if you don't use the *blocksize* that gives you the best performance; the only way to know *the best performance blocksize*, is to try with various blocksizes and test; but in your case, that doesn't seem a good idea (*your are manipulating your sensible data*)... You can do something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

where `/dev/sda` is your current disk and `/dev/sdb` is your new disk (this use the default blocksize of 512 bytes, that could be very slow)

In this case, while `dd` is cloning your current disk in your new disk, you get nothing on your terminal (I mean: nothing on `stdout` or `stderr`); this is far from good, specially, in a case like this, where you are cloning a large disk, so, in most recent versions of `dd`, you can use `status=progress` to get a feedback in your terminal, like this:

```
 dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

Read your `dd` manual and search for `status`; if you don't have that option, and for whatever reason you are doing your cloning with that version of `dd`, your can use `pv` with `dd`, like this:

```
 dd if=/dev/sda | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb
```

`pv` stands for pipeview, and you get almost the same effect that with `status=progress` on newer versions of `dd`

or, even better, faster and simpler:

`pv --progress /dev/sda > /dev/sdb`

(`pv` will automatically choose the "*best/faster*" block size for you)

---

## If not...

(or in any case, really)

Even tough you can use `dd` too, it's a little more complex: you need to do one thing if A > B and another if B > A, and, besides, take account on your partition table type *(ms-dos,gpt,...)*, so... better than that, use `partclone`, or even `Clonezilla`

`partclone` is another program that you can use from your terminal (maybe, not installed by default) but, it's much more adequate for your task... `partclone` understand perfectly about filesystem (it's much more high level than `dd`, and, among other things, doesn't waste time coping the empty bytes in your file system)

`Clonezilla` it's a little linux distro especially designed for your task and alike; take a look here:

> https://clonezilla.org/

(In fact, `Clonezilla` will try to use `partclone`, but, if your prefer, it can use `dd` too)

Comment: Your `dd` commands read and write 512 byte blocks, which causes complexity for SSDs that use 4KB blocks  Ideally, just use `cat` (it'll be so much faster). But if you insist on using `dd` please use the `bs` option to use decent a block size, eg `bs=32M`

Comment: yeah; I've made that clear in my answer here: `this can be slow, specially if you don't use the blocksize that gives you the best performance; the only way to know the best performance blocksize, is to try with various blocksizes and test` and here: `(this use the default blocksize of 512 bytes, that could be very slow)`: I've give her/him the bare bones and then, she/he can try with several different blocksizes, dropping the cache after each try with something like `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, or even use `bs=32M` directly

Answer (score 1):

**Disk Imaging method**

Attach the SSD using a quality USB-to-SATA adapter or through the secondary ports on your laptop if available.

You could boot into any LiveCD/USB environment and use `dd` command to clone the disks and it should work just fine.

If the source drive is /dev/sda, and destination is /dev/sdb,
the command would be `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

Please verify which drive is which before starting since this is the point where event a hint of carelessness could lead to data loss. (Source: me)

Afterwards all you would want to do is extend the last partition to the full length of the disk or create a new partition in that empty space, but this should not be a worry since the size of the source and target disks are the same.

**Cleaner method**

You can take a tar.gz dump of your Kubuntu distribution from a Live CD and unpack it later on a ext4/xfs partition to transplant your installation.

You will have to update the following in the new partition:

- Partition ID in /etc/fstab
- Reinstall grub using the new /boot directory